# Joomla tag links in articles url problem

Tags: articles, url, seo, tags

Having the latest Joomla 3.9.1, when I insert tags in articles, the url when I hover over the tags under the article from a category blog page is **example.com/component/tags/tag/my-example-tag**.

I have already created menu items to all of my tags and I visited directly the url for one of them, for instance **example.com/my-example-tag**, and it works, but still the url on the tags inside the category blog page under the article is **example.com/component/tags/tag/my-example-tag**.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it? Do you think it is a bug? Or does it have to do with theming?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Joomla 4.3.1. Were you able to resolve this problem? The tag cloud isn't respecting the hidden menu item that shows all tags, so they're being rendered in my home page template.